# How do you use Exslt.dyn (especially the 'evaluate' method) in Umbraco?

Tags: xslt, umbraco, exslt

I am trying to execute the string contained in an XSL variable.

Umbraco has hooks for several Exslt pieces, but it seems the Exslt.dyn (Exslt.dynamic) is not one of them.

How do you add it in? Acceptable methods (in order of preference:

1. Writing your own XSLT extension (possibly using existing Umbraco code for Exslt Dynamic).
2. Uploading the XSL from http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html into Umbraco.
3. Modifying the Umbraco source to add it (possibly using existing Umbraco code for Exslt Dynamic).

The reason I mention Exslt Dyanmic is because some Umbraco XSLT sources show a reference that I am assuming existing in some versions of Umbraco. I cannot find it in the source code, however. (Example: the XSL sources pasted in here: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/business-website-starter-pack/general-%28bugs,-feedback,-feature-requests%29/8085-Changing-the-first-day-to-fx-monday)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a confirmation that you can't implement the EXSLT `dyn:evaluate()` function with any reasonable effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Very few XSLT processors implement `dyn:evaluate()`** and Umbraco obviously doesn't use one of these.

There isn't anything you can do in this case.

Ask the Umbraco developers to incorporate an XSLT 2.0 processor in the future -- XSLT 2.0 has a *native* [**`<xsl:function>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-function) instruction for defining functions that can be referenced in any XPath expression.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I am taking your "with any reasonable effort" to mean that option #3 (patch the source code) in my question is the only way to go.
I coded my way around it. Given the current status of the source (they are just shifting everything prior to a big 5.0 release...) I wouldn't get anywhere near a source code patch right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but if Exslt.ExsltDynamic is supported out of the box in the .Net implementation of XSLT, this should work. In your stylesheet add the namespace xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDynamic="urn:Exslt.ExsltDynamic" (as in the example you linked) and in the exclude-result-prefixes property add Exslt.ExsltDynamic to make it accessible in your xslt file.

Then you can just do something like  in your template.

Comment: Ha! Sounded good, "but: Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'urn:Exslt.ExsltDynamic'. "
Also note: in the Umbraco Source, they have taken the trouble to create .cs files for each Exslt namespace they implement (this doesn't prove that the .net 2.0 implementation since they might have coded these prior to .net 2.0).

Comment: No other Exslt functions are supported in .NET (XslCompiledTransform) except `common:node-set()`